# Django-haystack not updating index

Tags: django-haystack, xapian

Using [django-haystack 2.0.0](http://haystacksearch.org/) and xapian-haystack 2.0.0, migrated all code from 1.1.5 as it said in [docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migration_from_1_to_2.html).
Now my search_indexes.py looks like:

```
from haystack import indexes
from app.models import Post

class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(visible=True)
```

But when I go rebuild_index, it says:

> Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y
>
> Removing all documents from your index because you said so. All
>   documents removed.

With verbosity:

```
Skipping '<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Permission'>' - no index.
Skipping '<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'>' - no index.
...
Skipping '<class 'app.models.Post'>' - no index.
```

So, I don't know why haystack doesn't index this model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually add fields to your index, so under "text" add:

```
post1 = indexes.CharField(model_attr='postfield1', null=True)
```

And then in your post_text.txt index file template:

```
{{object.post1}}
```

Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have not added which fields you want to search for, in your

> search_indexes.py

file.
You have to do like:

```
class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
data = indexes.CharField(model_attr='data', blank=True, null=True)

def get_model(self):
    return Post

def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    return self.get_model().objects.filter(visible=True)
```

and then create a directory structure like `templates/search/indexes/'app_name'/post_text.txt`. Now run command `./manage.py rebuild_index`.